# Divisão no sqlserver

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou usando o SQL Server 2008, eu gostaria de dividir 50/100 por exemplo e me retornar 0.05. Porém está me retorna 0, segue o que eu tentei fazer:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

É preciso ficar atento ao tipo de dados do denominador e do divisor. Quando ambos são expressões numéricas no domínio dos números inteiros, ocorre a divisão inteira, obtendo-se quociente inteiro. Quando ao menos um deles é fracionário, ocorre a divisão desejada.

```
-- divisão inteira 
SELECT 50 / 100

-- divisão fracionária
PRINT 50.0 / 100
PRINT 50 / 100.0
PRINT 1.0 * 50 / 100
```

Answer (score 2):

A resposta do José está correta, mas complementando também pode ser assim:

```
declare @numero decimal(10,3) = 50;

set @numero = @numero / 100;

print @numero
```

Já declarando a variável como decimal, também funciona

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIT**: Desta forma também funciona:

```
print convert(decimal(10,2), 50) / 100
```

Primeiro você está convertendo o número 50 em decimal, e depois dividindo ele

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, imagino eu, que em questão de performance, a resposta do José será melhor, pois das duas formas que eu mostrei, uma declara variável e seta ela, e da outra forma usa o `convert`, e na resposta do José, isso já é meio que "automático".. então creio eu que a forma dele é melhor em performance.

Comment: Maike, no dia a dia o que ocorre é o uso de variáveis. Se as 2 variáveis (denominador e divisor) forem "expressões numéricas no domínio dos números inteiros", basta multiplicar por 1.0 uma delas, antes de efetuar a divisão.